# Why Does my Dynamically Allocated Array only contain one result?

Tags: c, linux

When I run this code on my linux machine I've noticed when i try to iterate and store various user inputted strings, it results in the entire array containing only one value. Can someone help me out here?

It seems to only be holding the memory address of buf (thus resulting in the same string for each entry), when i want the actual values to be placed inside my allocated array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
 {
   char *name;
 } Task;



int main()
{
   /*Allocate 5 sets of Task structs onto the heap. 
   which we access   the starting address with our pointer*/
   
   Task *my_list = malloc(sizeof(Task)*5);


  /*user input*/

  char buf[100]="\0";

  /*loop through our allocated array and fill with user entered tasks*/
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      printf("Enter task:\t");
      fgets(buf,99,stdin);
      my_list[i].name = buf;
      //bzero(buf,100);

   }

  /*now let's print the allocated array*/
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       printf("%d:%s\n",i,my_list[i].name);
   }


   /*now let's free the data*/
   free(my_list);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not allocating any memory for each `Task`'s name.

Comment: All `Task::name`'s point at the same `buf`

Comment: Instead of `my_list[i].name = buf`, use `strdup`

Comment: ... and if you don't have `strdup` (it won't become standard until C23), write your own. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It's because in my struct i have a char pointer. Rather than a statically allocated array with a defined byte size.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're assigning the `name` **pointer** to a single, allocated spot in memory (`buf`).  You need to create a newly allocated memory location using `strdup` or similar.

IE, change:

```
      my_list[i].name = buf;
```

to

```
      my_list[i].name = strdup(buf);
```

The other alternative is to allocate a fixed size within the structure:

```
typedef struct
 {
   char name[100];
 } Task;
```

and then read directly into it:

```
      fgets(my_list[i].name,99,stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

so all ur objects of class Task having pointer name are pointing to the same address i.e &buf so you get the last updated value of buf as all the *name are pointing to the same address(&buf)

```
   int main()
 {
    /*Allocate 5 sets of Task structs onto the heap.
   which we access   the starting address with our pointer*/

    Task *my_list = (Task*)malloc(sizeof(Task)*5);


    /*user input*/

    //  char buf[100]="\0";

  /*loop through our allocated array and fill with user entered tasks*/
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  printf("Enter task:\t");
  char *buf=(char*)malloc(100);
  fgets(buf,100,stdin);
  my_list[i].name = buf;
  //bzero(buf,100);

 }

  /*now let's print the allocated array*/
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
   printf("%d:%s\n",i,my_list[i].name);
 }


 /*now let's free the data*/
  free(my_list);

 return 0;
   }
```